# Statistical methods for unbalanced designs

Tags: logistic, statistical-power, unbalanced-classes

During a survey the number of participants in 2 groups vary by 1:2. Which statistical analysis method is most appropriate and why?
Mann Whitney U test is the best test ? with good statistical power or ? suggest

Answer (score 1):

You have not given much concrete information about your data or goals, so my answer will have to be generic and sparse. I am assuming you want to know if the two groups give data centered at different values (perhaps means or medians).

- The type of data you get from the survey would ordinarily govern the choice
  between a Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon two-sample rank sum test (ordinal categorical data)
  or a two-sample t test (normal data) or some other kind of test.
- The great disparity of sample sizes would not pose a difficulty for most
  tests for difference in location. [The only caveat is that some nonparametric tests, such as Mann-Whitney, may not work if the smaller sample is less than half a dozen.]
- However, for a given total number of subjects (say 300), power
  would be better with 150 in each of the two groups than with 200 in one group and 100 in the other. For that reason, many 'power and sample size' procedures, in which
  you seek the number of subjects to achieve the power of detecting a specified
  difference in location (if real), give results only for balanced designs (in which the groups have equal sample sizes). This may give some people the incorrect impression
  that balanced designs are mandatory.

If you want to share what kind of data you will have, how many responses and what kind of responses the surveys provide, and what you want to know from doing the test, perhaps someone can provide an answer better targeted to your situation.